# Simulate gamepad input in UWP app on Xbox

Tags: c#, uwp, xbox, gamepad

I am trying to simulate user's input in UWP app running on Xbox. At first I tried to press a key via `InjectedInputKeyboardInfo` and it works fine.

```
var inputInjector = InputInjector.TryCreate();

InjectedInputKeyboardInfo inputKeyboardInfo = new InjectedInputKeyboardInfo
{
    KeyOptions = InjectedInputKeyOptions.ScanCode,
    ScanCode = 22
};

inputInjector.InjectKeyboardInput(new[] { inputKeyboardInfo });
```

Then I tried to press a key on gamepad and it actually does nothing. No error, no exception.

```
InjectedInputGamepadInfo info = new InjectedInputGamepadInfo
{
    Buttons = GamepadButtons.A
};

inputInjector.InjectGamepadInput(info);
```

I updated my package manifest:

- added namespace `xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"`
- added `IgnorableNamespaces="rescap"`
- added capability `<rescap:Capability Name="inputInjectionBrokered" />`

My app has min/target version 16299.
My Xbox runs on 16299.4055.

Comment: Thanks for reporting this issue. This has been a logged issue in our system, the related team is investigating this issue.

Comment: @FangPeng-MSFT Any progress?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From OS build 17134 there is new API which can be used to simulate Xbox One controller, keyboard or mouse.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/xbox-apps/uwp-remoteinput-api

Comment: Do you manage to use it? I am trying connecting with webSocket but it's not working, it's just stuck on "connecting" on Postman.